# Android BaseExpandableListAdapter - How does the getView method work

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am having a ExpandableList that extands a adapter BaseExpandableListAdapter .

> **I want to change the child view when child view gets clicked**

the adding of a children in ExpandableListView gets done by :

```
    @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {}
```

How do I change childs when one of them gets clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use OnChildClickListener.

don't change childview directly, just modify the data associated with the child and, refresh the listview by something like notifyDatasetChanged()